# Get current song from Icecast using XPath

Tags: php, html, xpath

So I tried to get the "Current Song" as echo in a PHP file using XPath.
I tried to echo the file_get_content and it returns the webpage I'm trying to get the content from, however it seems that I can't filter the webpage content using XPath. It should echo only the Current Song.

This is what I've tried:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$html = file_get_contents('http://185.40.20.83/radio/8000/');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]')->item(0);
echo $node->textContent;
?>
```

I'm trying this for over one hour and I'm loosing hope because I don't see what's the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `$node` to :

```
$node = $xpath->query('//table//tr[./td[text()="Current Song:"]]/td[2]')->item(0);
```

or

```
$node = $xpath->query('//table//tr[./td[text()="Current Song:"]]/td[2]');
echo $node[0]->nodeValue;
```

Output:

```
Chmst - Pump Up The Jam
```

Comment: So apparently, XPath is handling the input differently from an XML to HTML DOM. Thanks. It worked